# rails: force a model to be not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a very specific situation where I want to force an instance of a model not valid.

Something like this:

```
user = User.new
user.valid? #true
user.make_not_valid!
user.valid? #false
```

Any way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
validate :forced_to_be_invalid

def make_not_valid!
  @not_valid = true
end

private

def forced_to_be_invalid
  errors.add(:base, 'has been forced to be invalid') if @not_valid
end
```

Comment: This is good, but it invalidates the whole class and not just an instance. Unless @broisatse implies class << before his code.

Comment: @jforberg - `@not_valid` is an instance variable, so it will only make given instance invalid.

Comment: @BroiSatse Oh, yes of course. Sorry, I was thinking about my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant that I found useful for testing:

```
invalid_instance = MyModel.new
class << invalid_instance
  validate{ errors.add_to_base 'invalid' }
end
```